# ESP-C3 ADC conversion speed in single shot mode

Tags: esp32, adc

I am writing motor control software for the ESP32-C3 using the LED-PWM, which is really working fine. I'd like to go with synchronous AD conversion at 20 kHz.

I am not able to make the ADCs running faster than 30 µs conversion time. My target is 3 conversions in 20 µs time frame.
Is this not realistic with the ADC? Reading all the manuals I got the picture that the SAR ADC requires 25 cycles for 12 Bit and I am operating it at 40 MHz, so I expected to be save in the 5 µs conversion time range.
The tested code:

Comment: "The tested code:"? Where is it?